# Adding a new button in spring mvc 2.5

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to add new PRINT button in my existing jsp page that will display the content of existing jsp page using spring mvc 2.5

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cool! I want a Tesla S :)

What do you mean by "display the content of existing jsp page"? Can you not use a hyperlink to its URL?

Does it have to be a button? Do you want to do a POST request or a GET?

Are you trying to make the page more printer-friendly?

If you're trying to make it printer-friendly, I would suggest doing this with CSS, where you hide certain parts of the page using @media queries.

Please clarify your question and I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.It should be print button and display the content of existing jsp means i want to display few fields in my new jsp after clicking on print button.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.It should be print button and display the content of existing jsp means i want to display few fields in my new jsp after clicking on print button.